# Where does the summation formula $(c^n - 1)/(c -1)$ come up? What does it apply to?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

A solution I'm looking at employs this formula to find the sum of a finite series, but I haven't been able to find any information on this formula online or in my textbooks. Where does it come from, and what situations does it apply to? (It doesn't seem to be a reorganization of the formula for finite geometric sums...)

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the summation formula $(c^n-1)/(c-1)$"? Do you mean the identity $\sum_{k = 0}^{n-1} c^k = \frac{c^n-1}{c-1}$?

Comment: It is a geometric sum. It comes up whenever you ehm, sum geometries.

Comment: It is just the sum of a finite geometric series (you seem to know that). It's useful in very many places.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825654/intuition-behind-the-finite-geometric-series-formula) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426699/double-induction-example-1-q-q2-q3-cdots-qn-1-qn-frac) help ?

Comment: @EthanBolker Oh...I thought the sum of a finite geometric series was $\frac{a_0(1-r^n)}{1-r}$?

Comment: Suppose $a_0=1$?

Comment: @JamesRonald yes it is special case $a_0 = 1$

Answer (score 3):

It comes from the high-school formula:
$$a^n-b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+\dots+ab^{n-2}+b^{n-1})$$
with $a=1$.